# How To Only Show Spinner and An Alert When Form Is Submitted

Tags: javascript, html, forms, ajaxform

I use ajax for form submission so the webpage does not need to refresh or reload on submit.

I am trying to show a spinner and an alert only when the form gets submitted to let users know that their message has been submitted.

I already have the spinner where I want it to appear when the submit button is clicked but I do not know how to make it show only when the form gets submitted.

As for the alert, I have tried to implement it in the ajax but only the `failure` alert shows when something is wrong and the form isn't submitted.

The form just closes when it gets submitted successfully without letting the users know their message has been submitted.

I will appreciate any help on how to show the spinner and an alert only when the form gets submitted. Thanks.

Code below;

```js
function openForm() {
        document.getElementById("popupForm").style.display = "block";
      }
      function closeForm() {
        document.getElementById("popupForm").style.display = "none";
      }
       function spinner() {
        document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = "block";
    }
    
    function ajaxpost () {
  // (A) GET FORM DATA
  var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
  var data = new FormData(form);
 
  // (B) AJAX REQUEST
  // (B1) POST DATA TO SERVER, RETURN RESPONSE AS TEXT
  fetch("https://formsubmit.co/69b386256f5ab9111d636b4f38523dd6", { method:"POST", body:data })
  .then(res=>res.text())
 
  // (B2) SHOW MESSAGE ON SERVER RESPONSE
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    if (response == "OK") { alert("SUCCESSFUL!"); }
    else { alert("FAILURE!"); }
  })
 
  // (B3) OPTIONAL - HANDLE FETCH ERROR
  .catch((err) => { console.error(err); });
 
  // (C) PREVENT FORM SUBMIT
  return false;
}
```

```css
* {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      .openBtn {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: left;
      }
      .openButton {
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #1c87c9;
        color: white;
        padding: 14px 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: fixed;
      }
      .loginPopup {
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .formPopup {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        left: 45%;
        top: 5%;
        transform: translate(-50%, 5%);
        border: 3px solid #999999;
        z-index: 9;
      }
      .formContainer {
        width: 400px;
        max-width: 100%;
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: #fff;
        height: 300px;
        overflow: scroll;
}

      .formContainer input[type=text],
      .formContainer input[type=password] {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 15px;
        margin: 5px 0 20px 0;
        border: none;
        background: #eee;
      }
      .formContainer input[type=text]:focus,
      .formContainer input[type=password]:focus {
        background-color: #ddd;
        outline: none;
      }
      .formContainer .btn {
        padding: 12px 20px;
        border: none;
        background-color: #8ebf42;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        opacity: 0.8;
      }
      .formContainer .cancel {
        background-color: #cc0000;
      }
      .formContainer .btn:hover,
      .openButton:hover {
        opacity: 1;
      }
       #spinner {
        display: none;
    }

    .loading {
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border-top-color: #1ecd97;
        border-left-color: #1ecd97;
        animation: spin 1s infinite ease-in;
    }

    @keyframes spin {
        0% {
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        100% {
            transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="openBtn">
      <button class="openButton" onclick="openForm()"><strong>Open Form</strong></button> 
 
 <div class="loginPopup">
      <div class="formPopup" id="popupForm">
        <form class='formContainer' id='myForm' onsubmit='return ajaxpost()'>
          <h2>Please Fill The Form</h2>
          <label for="email">
            <strong>E-mail</strong>
          </label>
          <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" name="email" required>
         
          <br/>
         <center> <div id="spinner" class="loading"></div></center><br/>
          <button type="submit" class="btn" onclick="spinner()" >Log in</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It is showing html response instead of `ok` in `response`, please check once.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean - Ram Ratan Bairar 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change part of your code like below:

I have mark ** as new code to place in code and describe what exactly I do

You can use that mark to know what is the new code I have write

```js
function openForm() {
  document.getElementById("popupForm").style.display = "block";
}
function closeForm() {
  document.getElementById("popupForm").style.display = "none";
}
function spinner() {
  document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = "block";
}
function hideSpinner() {  // **
  document.getElementById("spinner").style.display = "none";
}

function ajaxpost() {
  // (A) GET FORM DATA

  var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
  var data = new FormData(form);

  spinner();  // ** Show spinner
  
  // (B) AJAX REQUEST
  // (B1) POST DATA TO SERVER, RETURN RESPONSE AS TEXT
  fetch("https://formsubmit.co/69b386256f5ab9111d636b4f38523dd6", {
    method: "POST",
    body: data
  })
    // (B2) SHOW MESSAGE ON SERVER RESPONSE
    .then((response) => {

   // **  main point is use response.ok as condition that can know response is success or not precisely

      if (response.ok) {     // **  response have ok property that is a boolean if response success it will be true
        alert("SUCCESSFUL!");
        hideSpinner();   // ** hide spinner
        
      } else {
        alert("FAILURE!");
        hideSpinner();   // ** hide spinner
        
      }
    })

    // (B3) OPTIONAL - HANDLE FETCH ERROR
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
    });

  // (C) PREVENT FORM SUBMIT
  return false;
}
```

```css
* {
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      .openBtn {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: left;
      }
      .openButton {
        border: none;
        border-radius: 5px;
        background-color: #1c87c9;
        color: white;
        padding: 14px 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: fixed;
      }
      .loginPopup {
        position: relative;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .formPopup {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        left: 45%;
        top: 5%;
        transform: translate(-50%, 5%);
        border: 3px solid #999999;
        z-index: 9;
      }
      .formContainer {
        width: 400px;
        max-width: 100%;
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: #fff;
        height: 300px;
        overflow: scroll;
}

      .formContainer input[type=text],
      .formContainer input[type=password] {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 15px;
        margin: 5px 0 20px 0;
        border: none;
        background: #eee;
      }
      .formContainer input[type=text]:focus,
      .formContainer input[type=password]:focus {
        background-color: #ddd;
        outline: none;
      }
      .formContainer .btn {
        padding: 12px 20px;
        border: none;
        background-color: #8ebf42;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        opacity: 0.8;
      }
      .formContainer .cancel {
        background-color: #cc0000;
      }
      .formContainer .btn:hover,
      .openButton:hover {
        opacity: 1;
      }
       #spinner {
        display: none;
    }

    .loading {
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
        width: 60px;
        height: 60px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border-top-color: #1ecd97;
        border-left-color: #1ecd97;
        animation: spin 1s infinite ease-in;
    }

    @keyframes spin {
        0% {
            transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
        100% {
            transform: rotate(360deg);
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="openBtn">
  <button class="openButton" onclick="openForm()"><strong>Open Form</strong></button>

  <div class="loginPopup">
    <div class="formPopup" id="popupForm">
      <form class='formContainer' id='myForm' onsubmit='return ajaxpost()'>
        <h2>Please Fill The Form</h2>
        <label for="email">
          <strong>E-mail</strong>
        </label>
        <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" name="email" required>

        <br />
        <center>
          <div id="spinner" class="loading"></div>
        </center><br />
        <button type="submit" class="btn" onsubmit="ajaxpost()">Log in</button>   <!---  **  change to sumbit and call ajaxpost  -->
        <button type="button" class="btn cancel" onclick="closeForm()">Close</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you Jay for your solution, but I noticed that only the Alert shows not the spinner..

Comment: @BABOSAMMONG
because I did not attatch css in my code so it does not shown
if you want i can add it